# How to Change Order and Rename Links in customer navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, custom, navigation

How to Change placing order for customer navigation, I need order as showing in below Image:

[image]
and also how to Rename the text (eg: Instead of my product list I need My Grocery List)

Comment: Gud question rajiv please try it in local magento and reply me when it works. thanks advance.

Comment: remove cache and session after changing the xml file and one important point i.e you have do the changes customer.xml from your current theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Please follow the below steps.

I have tried in default magento 1.9.3.1 and got the solution for this.

Path: 
**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml**

```
<reference name="left_first">
            <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">

            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>

            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>xxxx</name><path>xxx/yyyyy/zzzzz/</path><label>My Products List</label></action>

            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>

            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"><name>downloadable_products</name><path>downloadable/customer/products</path><label>My Downloadable Products</label></action>


            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>

            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>


                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>


            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>

        </block>
    </reference>
```

Please find the screenshot:

[image]

**Note:** go to respected layout file(.xml) from your module and find for `**reference name="customer_account_navigation"**` copy the action section and paste one by one in the customer.xml as shown above format. Thanks

Comment: HI, Thanks for your answer !! I am using 1.9.2.2, I found the customer.xml on mytheme/default/layout/ but I am confused Where I need to place this code [link](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/58c03fdbde9f331a7f334174/58f12e6d90f7ebeacb23a94a/5a25c20f8c98e4ca58f5f26fd86d86ff/order.xml). Here my customer.xml file  [link](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/58c03fdbde9f331a7f334174/58f12e6d90f7ebeacb23a94a/daf0f7136f3fb1bdea38401c5b40b26c/customer.xml)

Comment: Please check the reference name "left_first" in your customer.XML and place the above code.

Comment: HI, I didn't find any left_first in my customer.XML, even I searched in base, default, and my theme. Only 'left' is available for the customer.XML  I already sent my customer.xml file in the previous comment please check that one and please suggest me

Comment: you are most welcome @rajiv..have a nice day and happy coding...